# Changing background color of Kendo UI Calendar using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

The help I need now should be relatively simple. 
I can't seem to get the javascript to fire when the calendar is created/loaded.

here's my javascript, it is placed in the same .cshtml file as the calendar. the script block is below the calendar html.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#Trafikkalender').onLoad(function() {
        var calendar = $(this);
        var currentDate = kendo.toString(calendar.value(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
        var param = { date: currentDate }
        var url = $('#calArrayPostUrl').data('url');
        $.post(url, param, function(data) {
            var body = calendar.find('tbody');

            var rows = body.getElementsByTagName('tr');

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                for (var j = 0; cols.length; j++) {
                    var col = cols[j];
                    col.addClass(data[i][j]);
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

and here's the calendar

```
@(Html.Kendo().Calendar()
              .Name("Trafikkalender")
              .Culture("sv-SE")
              .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width: 100%;"})
              .Events(e => e.Change("DateClick").Navigate("Navigate"))
              .Format("dd MM yyyy")

              //.MonthTemplate("#<div class=" + TrafficData.GetTrafficDate("#= data.value #").CSSClass + ">#")
              )
```

my problem is that the javascript is not running, it does not stick on the breakpoint at least. 
in case a question should arise to the source of the data parameter and what it looks like, it is a 2-dimensional array declared as string[,] in c#, it is returned as a Json string from the controller.

the url is fetched from a hiddenfield defined as such

```
<input type="hidden" id="calArrayPostUrl" data-url="@Url.Action("CalendarCellClasses")"/>
```

Comment: would it be easier to do a on page load instead? how do I do that with jQuery/javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the id of the calendar or change the jquery selector because you have  .Name("Trafikkalender") and you are doing jQuery('#Trafikkalender') which searches for an element with the id #Trafikkalender to change background color. After javascript code runs you should change the background color using CSS like here: http://dojo.telerik.com/UDudA